# Orchard Extensible Framwework

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, orchardcms

I am trying to use Orchard extensible Framework as a base of my application.

I only want the framework and core modules but don't want any of the database access stuff.

Does anyone know how I can get rid of this database and configure it to not read from the database and lunch my module on startup instead of Orchard startup module

Thanks

Comment: Not really sure what your question is about? When you make an orchard module you hook into orchard and you can display your module on a url  route your create, you could also use an action filter and display any content you want in any zone on the home page too.

Answer (score 0):

You could (with considerable work) implement your own data access provider, but Orchard relies heavily on the database for everything at a core level: Settings, migrations, etc. You need the startup module for the Orchard context so that all of the framework and core modules can function. You would probably be better off customizing/overhauling everything on top of the core rather than trying to have your own module replace the startup module.